# how can be the assertThat be used while making the junit testing as it is causing compile time error?

Tags: java

```
package com.rectrix.methods;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import java.util.List;

import org.junit.Test;

public class EmployeeCollectionTest {
@Test
public void testAddEmployees() {

    EmployeeCollection emp =new EmployeeCollection("suneel",21,1234);
    assertThat(emp.addEmployees(),is("showing employees"));

}
```

}

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: My answer is **one** possible explanation; but in order to really help you: A) post your EmmployeeCollection source code B) take the time to **properly** format your input!

Answer (score 0):

The point is that assertThat has this signature:

```
 assertThat(T, Matcher<T>)
```

In other words:

the first parameter has some type T; the second one needs a `Matcher<T>`

In your case, you are using a `Matcher<String>` - because you are using `is("showing...")`.

And most likely, a method called addEmployees() does not return a string!
Thus a compiler error!

In order to fix that - you have to look at getEmployess(), and what that is returning!